# Laravel Broadcast in not working with Pusher (not showing alert) in existing project

Tags: php, laravel, events, websocket, pusher

bootstrap.js file

in this file i am usgin the laravel echo with npm to show the alert in the blade file , that should be show the alert after hitgn the event but it is not showing be the alert neither giving any error

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'anyKey',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
});

window.Echo.channel('chat').listen('.testEvent', (e) => {
    alert('socket here');
    console.log(e)
  });
```

event file

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class testEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('chat');
    }

}
```